# Changing the text of item from loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the text, or remove one letter from a list of items coming from the database, I have tried different simple jQuery methods, but none seems to be working.

I have tried jQuery .find(), .children(), .text(), .html().

```
if(requiredVisits == 1){
  $(`.upcoming-item${i + 1} `).find('.how-earned').text('EARNED FROM 1 VISIT')
}


$('#upcoming-rewards').append(`
    <item class="upcoming-reward-item upcoming-item${i + 1} available">
    <span>
        <p style="line-height: 16px" class="reward-item reward${i + 1}">${reward}</p>
    <span id="how-earned" class="how-earned">EARNED FROM ${requiredVisits} VISITS</span>
    </span>
   </item>
`)
```

I also tried just to console.log the text written and I get a 'undefined' or just blank result. So maybe I'm not traveling correctly to the span wanted. Any help would be great! :)

The expected result would be "EARNED FROM 1 VISIT" not "EARNED FROM 1 VISITS"

Comment: `console.log($(\`.upcoming-item${i + 1}\`).find('.how-earned').length)` and tell us what it says.  All good debugging starts with logs or debugger statements

Comment: Though your question is slightly confusing.  You have your append **after** the first conditional.  If you are appending after the conditional, it's not going to exist for the conditional.  Which also begs the question why you are generating incorrect html in the first place that you have to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your html generation.  Don't try to fix it after the fact, if possible.

```
$('#upcoming-rewards').append(`
    <item class="upcoming-reward-item upcoming-item${i + 1} available">
        <span>
            <p style="line-height: 16px" class="reward-item reward${i + 1}">${reward}</p>
            <span id="how-earned" class="how-earned">EARNED FROM ${requiredVisits} VISIT${requiredVisits > 1 ? 'S' : ''}</span>
        </span>
    </item>
`);
```

Comment: I didn't knew you could do this, but it worked like a charm! Thank you!!

Comment: `${expression}` can be anything.  It's just expected to return a final value at the end

Comment: FWIW, I typically do `!== 1` instead of `> 1` because oftentimes I have to handle display for `0` (zero) instances, which is usually pluralized.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the appropriate verbiage initially instead of trying to update it...

```
var visitsText = (requiredVisits === 1) ? 'VISIT' : 'VISITS';

$('#upcoming-rewards').append(`
    <item class="upcoming-reward-item upcoming-item${i + 1} available">
    <span>
        <p style="line-height: 16px" class="reward-item reward${i + 1}">${reward}</p>
    <span id="how-earned" class="how-earned">EARNED FROM ${requiredVisits} ${visitsText}</span>
    </span>
   </item>
`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to attempt changing the text of an element before actually creating it. Try moving

```
if(requiredVisits == 1){
    $(`.upcoming-item${i + 1} `).find('.how-earned').text('EARNED FROM 1 VISIT')
}
```

to AFTER the .append() action.